# Get initial view magnification property of a pdf with PDFBox

Tags: java, pdfbox

The Adobe Acrobat Document Properties, Initial View tab displays "Magnification" with values such as Default, Fit Page and 100%. I'm trying to review a folder of about 200 pdf files to identify the files where Magnification is not "Fit Width". I cannot figure out the PDFBox method to get initial view magnification. It's not a PDDocument MetadataKey. I'm lost in all the PDDocumentCatalog, PDPageDestination, PDPage... possibilities.

I tried listing PDDocument MetadataKeys, and PDDocument Keywords, and PDDocumentCatalog PageLayout and PageMode, and tested if PDDocumentCatalog OpenAction was an instance of PDPageFitWidthDestination, and listed page (0)'s COSName & COSBase pairs. No luck.

Comment: IMHO it is `doc.getDocumentCatalog().getOpenAction()` and then you check the type, it should be one of the "fit" types derived from `PDPageDestination`. Why didn't it work? Please share a file.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Following Tilman Hausherr's suggestion and with a lot of experimentation, I have developed the following code. It works for the alphabetic fit types, not numeric percentages.

```
private void displayInitialView(File pdfFile) {
    String pdfFilename = pdfFile.getName();
    String pageLayout = null;
    String fitWindowStr = null;
    String magnification = null;

    try {
        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(pdfFile);
        PDDocumentInformation docInfo = document.getDocumentInformation();
        PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = document.getDocumentCatalog();

        pageLayout = docCatalog.getPageLayout().toString();

        /*   For all my pdf's: viewerPreferences==null
        PDViewerPreferences     viewerPreferences   = docCatalog.getViewerPreferences();
        if(viewerPreferences==null) {
            document.close();
            System.out.println("ERROR viewerPreferences==null ? pdfFilename: " + pdfFilename);
            return;
        }
        fitWindowStr = Boolean.toString(viewerPreferences.fitWindow());
        */

        PDDestinationOrAction openAction = docCatalog.getOpenAction();
        if (openAction == null) {
            magnification = "Undetermined - possibly 'Default'";
        } else {
            PDActionGoTo actionGoTo = (PDActionGoTo) openAction;
            COSDictionary dictionary = actionGoTo.getCOSObject();
            if (!dictionary.containsKey("D")) {
                magnification = "Undetermined - no key 'D'";
            } else {
                COSBase cosBase = dictionary.getItem("D");
                COSArray cosArray = (COSArray) cosBase;
                Iterator<COSBase> iterator = cosArray.iterator();
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    COSBase cosBaseInArray = iterator.next();
                    if (cosBaseInArray instanceof COSName) {
                        COSName cosNameInArray = (COSName) cosBaseInArray;
                        String cosNameInArrayStr = cosNameInArray.getName();
                        if (cosNameInArrayStr.equals("XYZ")) {
                            magnification = "Actual Size or some %";
                        } else if (cosNameInArrayStr.equals("Fit")) {
                            magnification = "Fit Page";
                        } else if (cosNameInArrayStr.equals("FitH")) {
                            magnification = "Fit Width";
                        } else if (cosNameInArrayStr.equals("FitV")) {
                            magnification = "Fit Height";
                        } else if (cosNameInArrayStr.equals("FitBH")) {
                            magnification = "Fit Visible";
                        } else {
                            magnification = "Undetermined - unexpected cosname";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        document.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    System.out.println(pdfFilename + "," + pageLayout + "," + magnification);
}
```